# Counting number of Hits on yaws web application

Tags: apache, erlang, webserver, yaws, nitrogen

if i have a web application running from a yaws web server, how would i count the number of hits from users to my site? 
I have tried to use rudimentary methods of counting the number of lines in the `.access` file of my site found in the yaws logs like this:

```
$ cat PATH_TO_YAWS_LOGS/www.my_site.com.access | wc -l
```

Point me to a better way of finding out how many hits i have received sofar on my site running on top of yaws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're lucky, Yaws uses the ["Common Log Format"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) and thus [any analytics software supporting Apache should do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software) (for example "Webalizer", as mentioned there).